In R, how do I split and rearrange a cimg (or any file type) image?
Using R, I want to take an image:

remove the background
split into even layers along y axis (e.g. 1 pixel tall)
determine the width (x) of each layer
rearrange the layers based on the widths and replot

Is this possible?  Open to any way to achieve it (ideally I'd like to flatten the image and plot in ggplot for example - it can be just a flat colour)
So far I've tried using the imager package:
apple <- load.image("apple.jpg")
detect <- px.flood(apple, 1, 1, sigma = .3) 
apple[detect] <- 10 #to remove colour if needed
plot(apple, axes = FALSE)

